# May UIComponent#getFamily() return null or not?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, specifications

I would like to know wether the method `UIComponent#getFamily()` may return `null` or not? Mojarra 2.1.3 will throw an exception when returning `null` but MyFaces 2.1.3 not.

Does a component really need a family?

Comment: Would an empty string be ok then? No exceptions when it's empty. What is the preferred way of implementing a component that has no renderer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *I would like to know wether the method UIComponent.getFamily() may return null or not?*

This is nowhere **explicitly** documented. So I think this is a little oversight in the [spec](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr314/index.html)/[javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getFamily%28%29). You may want to post an [issue](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC) report about this at the spec guys.

---

> *Does a component really need a family?*

I've always specified them, so I've never seen the exception you got with Mojarra. If your component is rather unique, you could consider to just let it return the same value as component type (the class name) or if there are more related components, then the component's package name.

---

> *What is the preferred way of implementing a component that has no renderer?*

Return `null` on [`getRendererType()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getRendererType%28%29). You could prepare that by [`setRendererType(null)`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#setRendererType%28java.lang.String%29) in the component's constructor:

```
public MyComponent() {
    setRendererType(null); // This component doesn't have an renderer.
}
```

Comment: Thanks to that detailed answer! com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentSupport.isForm(UIComponent) at line 477 throws a NullPointerException because I return null in  getFamily(). Probably I should report that...

Comment: I saw you did it: http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-1037 Well done reporting :)